Error when running TurtleBot3 simulation on ROS2 Humble
I have installed ROS 2 Humble and Gazebo on WSL2 with GWSL. Gazebo alone works could be launched and works fine. However, when I try to follow this guide to launch Turtlebor3 simulation with Gazebo, I get the error
[ERROR] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has died [pid 1322, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_entity.py -entity burger -file /home/shengxue/turtlebot3_ws/install/turtlebot3_gazebo/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models/turtlebot3_burger/model.sdf -x 0.0 -y 0.0 -z 0.01 --ros-args'].
[gzclient-2] gzclient: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:728: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = gazebo::rendering::Camera; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = gazebo::rendering::Camera*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
[ERROR] [gzclient-2]: process has died [pid 1318, exit code -6, cmd 'gzclient'].

Error appears when I execute  ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo empty_world.launch.py. Please help.
